# Htaccess 301 redirect is only redirecting domain not also the page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect page `www.domain1.nl/page-old` to `www.domain2.nl/page-new`.

When `www.domain1.nl/page-old` is visited it redirects to: `www.domain2.nl/page-old`.

So the redirect sort of works, but only half. The domain is redirected, the page is not.

- Domain1 only has a .htaccess file in the root.
- Domain2 is a WordPress website.

We use apache 2.4 + php7.3 + CloudFlare (no rules set)

We tried multiple htaccess rules texts: Redirect 301, Redirect, RedirectMatch, RewriteRule. All same result.

In the .htaccess file of domain1.com:

```
Redirect 301 /page-old/ https://www.domain2.com/page-new/
```

Expected result would be:

`www.domain1.nl/page-old >> www.domain2.nl/page-new`

Actual result:

`www.domain1.nl/page-old >> www.domain2.nl/page-old`

Comment: your code seems working to me, probably the issue your having related with Domain2 just double check .htaccess file on Domain2, are there any redirect etc.

Comment: @anubhava, nope not helping.. unfortunately.

Comment: @Whatatimetobealive good idea, it contains a regular WordPress only .htaccess file.

Comment: @anubhava renaming the file and checking again. The name is correctly .htaccess

Comment: Just move your .htaccess away and visit `www.domain1.nl/page-old` to see what redirect you get

Comment: @anubhava In that case i get a: Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: ok now try this rule: `RedirectMatch 301 ^/page-old/ https://www.domain2.com/page-new/`

Comment: @anubhava nice! Finally, that works. After adding the first redirect, which worked, others started redirecting to the homepage.. after adding them 1 by 1 they all started redirecting correctly. Strange! But, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my answer in comment section here so that readers can find it easily later

You need to use this rule instead for precise matching:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/page-old/ https://www.domain2.com/page-new/
```

`Redirect` is non-regex directive that works with starts-with match.